# Volume Up + Power does not result in screenshot

Tags: iphone, screen-capture

I am using an Iphone 8 running iOS 14.6.

When I press Volume Up + Power no screenshot is taken. I press and release, and press and hold, and neither works.

I have reboot the device, and the issue did not resolve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iPhone 8 has a home button. To take a screenshot, press side button and home button.

For devices without a home button, press side button and volume up.

[Take a screenshot on your iPhone - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT200289)